# Há algum tipo em JavaScript que guarde dados de um file qualquer?

Tags: javascript, file-upload

Ex: Em um form num campo input do tipo file num html qualquer um usuário do meu sistema anexa um arquivo. Após apertar submit eu desejo que o file seja mantido em uma variável do JavaScript. Existe algum tipo capaz disso? Se não o que me recomendam fazer?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Pode fazer isso com `localStorage` usando a [`API file`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications).

Crie um *event handler* para o `input file` e salve no `localStorage`:

```
<input type="file" id="file">

<script>
var arq = document.body.querySelector("#file");

arq.addEventListener("change", function(){

   localStorage.setItem("arquivo",this.files[0].name);

});
</script>
```

Quando quiser chamar o nome do arquivo, use:

```
localStorage.getItem("arquivo");
```

Answer (score -1):

Sim só criar uma variável e atribuir a ela `document.getElementById('input').files` (array de arquivos selecionados), se você quer apenas um arquivo use `.files[0]`

O JavaScript possui o objeto `File`, ele possui os dados do arquivo (tamanho, última data de modificação, nome, tipo...) e um `Blob`, em geral esse tipo pode ser usado em qualquer contexto de um `Blob` tradicional.

[Lei mais](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/File)

Comment: Se eu quiser mais de um arquivo, posso usar esse .files[0] com outro índice?

Comment: claro, pode fazer um loop para pegar os dados de todos arquivos